# Getting a random sample from large pandas dataframe by column value

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
#       Name        City
1       John        NYC
2       Doe         Berlin
3       Jonathan    Tokyo
4       Andrew      Barcelona
5       Heather     London
..      ......      ......
..      ......      ......
..      ......      ......
60000   Summer      Madrid
```

Lets say I have a list of cities like this: `[NYC, Berlin, Tokyo]`.

I need to get a sample of the above dataframe with the size of n (ex. n=200) that chooses rows randomly but according to the cities in the list. Preferably there should be the same number of rows per city.

How can I do this using pandas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It is a two steps process.

First create a subset based on your cities

```
subset_DF = DF[DF.cities.isin(['NYC', 'Berlin','Tokyo'])]
```

Then create your sample with pandas DataFrame methode

```
your_Sample = subset_DF.sample(n = 200)
```

or inline

```
your_Sample = DF[DF.cities.isin(['NYC', 'Berlin','Tokyo'])].sample(n = 200)
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem with this method however, is that the number samples per city are not the same. If I have a dataframe with say 10000 samples of NYC and 1000 of Berlin, I will get a pandas sample with say 170 samples of NYC and 30 of Berlin.

Comment: If you want equal number of samples you can reproduce this methode for each city value, and append those 3 results.

If you still want to do it in one step check the doc of sample

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html

Maybe the weight param could do the job

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this is the most efficient but this is how I did it:

Say you want N random rows per city. You can run a for loop over your unique city names and get the dataframe subset for each city name, and sample from this subset. In your case, this would look like this:

```py
df_list = list()
for city_name in df['City'].unique():
    df_subset = df.loc[df['City'] == city_name]
    df_list.append(df_subset.sample(N))
df_sample = pd.concat(df_list).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score -1):

sub_sample=df[df['City']=="NYC"] # choose all rows with "city"== "NYC"

sub_sample.iloc[0:20,:] # Suppose you need to extract  20 rows

In the same way to choose other two samples.